# How to make asyncio Semaphore sleep/delay after every batch of tasks is done?

Tags: python, asynchronous, time, async-await, python-asyncio

Consider the following partial script, which checks a list of URLs:

```
async def checker(url, session: ClientSession, sem: asyncio.Semaphore):
    
    async with sem:
        async with requests.get(url) as r
            return r.real_url, r.

async def asyncStarter(url_listy):
    listy = []
    
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(35)
        listy = await asyncProgress.gather(*(checker(u, session, sem) for a in url_listy)) 
    return listy
```

The Semaphore value is set at 35. This means at any time, 35 concurrent calls are being done.

I want Python to basically perform `time.sleep()` after every number of calls are finished. So for example, how can I make it here so that after every 100 URLs checked, Python waits 15 seconds? Then when another 100 URLs are checked, wait another 15 seconds, and so on? I'm looking at the docs for both asyncio and `time.sleep()`, and I can't figure out how to make this periodic. I'm also open to a delay every N seconds, that's cool too.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(number_of_seconds)`.   link is here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Unfortunately the page is unhelpful when it comes to my question. It doesn't explain how to make async sleep for a number of seconds after a period of time. For example, I might want 30-second sleeps punctuating three-minute async runs.

Comment: invoke a counter, and put the sleep in an if statement.  `if counter %100: await asyncio.sleep(number_of_seconds)`  this would sleep for n seconds every 100 url's.